# Unpivot columns in groups of three columns in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, unpivot

How can I accomplish this using PowerQuery? Data in on a worksheet.

Source table:

| Col1 | Col2 | Att1 | Att2 | Att3 | Att4 | Att5 | Att6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | DDD | X | O | alpha | delta | 100 | 400 |
| BBB | EEE | Y | P | beta | vega | 200 | 500 |

Desired table:

| Col1 | Col2 | CustomName1 | CustomName3 | CustomName3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | DDD | X | alpha | 100 |
| AAA | DDD | O | delta | 400 |
| BBB | EEE | Y | beta | 200 |
| BBB | EEE | P | vega | 500 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agnostic to column names and number of columns, pulling alternate columns

```
let Source =Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Leading = 2, Base=List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Leading),
Part1= Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,Base&List.Alternate(List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Base),1,1))),1),
Part2= Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,Base&List.Alternate(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Leading),1,1,1))),1)
in Part1 & Part2
```

If you need to, first add an leading index column, and change Leading=3, resort at end

**EDIT** to provide a final rename

```
let Source =Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Leading = 2, Base=List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Leading),
Part1= Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,Base&List.Alternate(List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Base),1,1))),1),
Part2= Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source,Base&List.Alternate(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Leading),1,1,1))),1),
NewNames= List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Leading)&List.Transform({1 .. List.Count(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Part1),Leading))}, each "Custom Name"&Text.From(_)),
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns( Part1 & Part2,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Part1),NewNames}))
in #"Rename"
```

Comment: Wow, it's a smart way to get the sub-table.

Comment: Similarly to taller_ExcelHome's solution. It returns `AAA, BBB, AAA, BBB`. Additionally, it 'switches' the columns and returns the right-most trio first.

Comment: This is great but makes me lose column names. In my real use case base has 29 columns.

Comment: edited to add a rename

Comment: If you mentioned the 29 columns, likely some of the other answers would have been different. That was an important point

Comment: Thanks. Next time I'll mention my real use case in addition to a simple replicable problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a typical unpivot.

3 steps：

- drop columns
- rename columns
- combine (merge) two tables

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    add_index = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    tab1 = Table.RemoveColumns(add_index,{"Att2", "Att4", "Att6"}),
    rename_tab1 = Table.RenameColumns(tab1,{{"Att1", "cn1"}, {"Att3", "cn2"}, {"Att5", "cn3"}}),
    tab2 = Table.RemoveColumns(add_index,{"Att1", "Att3", "Att5"}),
    rename_tab2 = Table.RenameColumns(tab2,{{"Att2", "cn1"}, {"Att4", "cn2"}, {"Att6", "cn3"}}),
    combine_tab = Table.Combine({rename_tab1, rename_tab2}),
    sort_row = Table.Sort(combine_tab,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    output = Table.RemoveColumns(sort_row,{"Index"})
in
    output
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I don't see how that will unpivot the columns.

Comment: @SuavestArt Just try it and validate the result.

Comment: The result is correct but the order is wrong: It returns `AAA, BBB, AAA, BBB` while the requirement is `AAA, AAA, BBB, BBB`.

Comment: @VBasic2008, just sort output by 1st column

Comment: @Denis Thanks, I'm such a newb, I almost didn't find the sort feature. Now that I found it, I'm wondering if `B` came first, the sorting wouldn't be useful. Got any other ideas?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Adding an index column to reserve the order of original data rows.

Answer (score 1):

Three approaches:

1. Combine unpivot related info into table and expand it.
   [image]

---

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnR0VNJRcnFxAZIRQOwPxIk5BRmJQDolNacERBsaGABJEyAZqxOt5OTkBOS5uroCyUggDgDipFSwwrLUdBBlBFZvClIfCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Col1 = _t, Col2 = _t, Att1 = _t, Att2 = _t, Att3 = _t, Att4 = _t, Att5 = _t, Att6 = _t]),
    #"Created data type" = Table.CombineColumnsToRecord(Source, "Data type", {"Att1", "Att3", "Att5"}, [DisplayNameColumn="Att1", TypeName="Excel.DataType"]),
    #"Created data type1" = Table.CombineColumnsToRecord(#"Created data type", "Data type.1", {"Att2", "Att4", "Att6"}, [DisplayNameColumn="Att2", TypeName="Excel.DataType"]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Created data type1", "Custom", each Table.FromRows({
    Record.FieldValues([Data type]), 
    Record.FieldValues([Data type.1])
    })),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Data type", "Data type.1"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}, {"CustomName1", "CustomName2", "CustomName3"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

2. Using straight forward `unpivot` approach with pre Columns Merge and post Column Split:

---

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnR0VNJRcnFxAZIRQOwPxIk5BRmJQDolNacERBsaGABJEyAZqxOt5OTkBOS5uroCyUggDgDipFSwwrLUdBBlBFZvClIfCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Col1 = _t, Col2 = _t, Att1 = _t, Att2 = _t, Att3 = _t, Att4 = _t, Att5 = _t, Att6 = _t]),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Att5", type text}}, "en-150"),{"Att1", "Att3", "Att5"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns", {{"Att6", type text}}, "en-150"),{"Att2", "Att4", "Att6"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.1"),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Merged Columns1", {"Col1", "Col2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"CustomName1", "CustomName2", "CustomName3"})
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

3. Solution offered by [taller_ExcelHome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085301/6165594) with a bit more compact syntax:

---

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnR0VNJRcnFxAZIRQOwPxIk5BRmJQDolNacERBsaGABJEyAZqxOt5OTkBOS5uroCyUggDgDipFSwwrLUdBBlBFZvClIfCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Col1 = _t, Col2 = _t, Att1 = _t, Att2 = _t, Att3 = _t, Att4 = _t, Att5 = _t, Att6 = _t]),
    Custom1 = Table.Combine({
Table.RenameColumns(Source[[Col1],[Col2],[Att1],[Att3],[Att5]],{{"Att1","CustomName1"},{"Att3","CustomName2"},{"Att5","CustomName3"}}),
Table.RenameColumns(Source[[Col1],[Col2],[Att2],[Att4],[Att6]],{{"Att2","CustomName1"},{"Att4","CustomName2"},{"Att6","CustomName3"}})
})
in
    Custom1
```